# Multiple Div Classes Not Working

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, ads

I seem to have run into a snag while working on a site.

What I'm trying to do is display certain sized ads only on certain devices (small ads = mobile, large ads = desktop, ect...) and make them display:none on all other devices outside of a certain pixel range.

So far everything is looking good; I've setup all the css classes like so:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 799px) {
  .site-main {
     margin: 0;
   }

   #secondary {
     clear: both;
     float: none;
     width: auto;
     display: none;
   }

  .tablet-only-ad {
     display:none !important;
   }
}
```

Everything works fine up until I get into the actual ad div... The current div is setup like this:

```
<div id="desktop-only-ad small-desktop-only-ad tablet-only-ad large-phone-only-ad">
<script>
ad script blah blah blah
</script>
</div>
```

I've tried copying all of the IDs into a class only, tried putting both class and id, spell checked, everything... Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do you want to happen, and what *does* happen?

Comment: I'm wanting it so that when someone looks at the site on a mobile device with the min-width: 0px and the max-width: 480px they wont see any other ads that are meant for other devices. To elaborate, I have 5 different ads of different sizes in 5 seperate divs on one page and they're all showing up right now on my phone. I'd like to only see one.

Comment: I think your logic is wrong here and don't respect the "Mobile first" approach. You should basically hide it by default and show it on bigger devices.

Comment: Bartdude, could you go more in detail there? If I understand you correctly you're saying to hide all other classes by default. But this is the only way I've found to hide the other classes because currently ALL of the classes are bypassing the @media screen and displaying on most devices.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you have your ad inside an ID, so to show/hide this, in your CSS you need to target an ID, not a class, i.e.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 799px) {  
....
#tablet-only-ad {       /* note ID not a class */
     display:none !important;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="desktop-only-ad small-desktop-only-ad tablet-only-ad large-phone-only-ad">
```

note: **class** not id!

class attribute can support multiple values separated white space, and you can reference a class in css file whit a dot (es: **.small-desktop-only-ad**)

id normaly is a unique value es: id="secondary" and can be referenced in css with #id (es: #secondary)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys, I figured it out. I believe it was a mixture of space errors and a misunderstanding of the class/div difference. After shortening the class names and a small bit of testing I can confirm that the proper ads are displaying correctly on every device.

**For reference to others:**

1. Check your class names and shorten them if possible to prevent spelling or space errors.
2. You can only have 1 ID on a page, but multiple classes. I needed to change the ID to CLASS to get multiple classes to work.

Here is an example of one of the completed divs:

```
<div class="desktop small-desktop large-phone phone">
<script>
AD SCRIPT
</script>
</div>
```

Note, each class (desktop, small-desktop, large-phone, phone) all have display: none; in the css under their designated @media sizes which means they wont display once included in a divs class if the media size doesn't meet the requirements. There are 5 total classes (desktop, small-desktop, tablet, large-phone, phone) all with different size parameters and by taking away "tablet" the ad specifically picked out for tablets now shows ONLY on tablets since the device size requirement has also been met.

The explanation may be a little confusing since I just relearned all the class/id stuff this morning, but hopefully it'll help out :)